# PHP output buffering callback yielding blank screen

Tags: php, callback

Here is the code:

```
 ob_start(array(&$dispatcher, 'outputCallback')); 
 include($file);
 ob_end_flush();

 function outputCallback($string) {
    if(ob_get_level() == 1) { 
        $static =& ParserStatic::getInstance();
        return $static->insertToppings($string);
    }
    return false;
  }
```

The problem is when I return `$string` it behaves OK, but when it executes 
the object assignment, it gives a blank screen. What's going wrong?

Comment: Are you still torturing yourself with PHP4? If not, then PHP5 basically forbids use of reference operator on objects. Remove &s.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking your web server's error log to see if PHP is throwing an error? That should help you identify the cause of the problem.

Comment: damn! somehow it unload the Static class, thanks for the help mate!